# PHP Commenting, Which way is correct?

Tags: php

I have

```
/**
  * This happens when the user is logged in.
  */
```

but is it meant to be like that?
Like is the spacing correct? Because I've seen

```
/**
  * This happens when the user is logged in.
  */
```

and others.

Which is classed as correct?

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but I see no difference. If the difference is tabs vs. spaces, then you should actually note that being the case.

Comment: Doesn't really strike me as a question with a correct or objective answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the difference between the two?

There's "no one right way" to comment something. Unless you're working under a corporate/team/group standard, pick what makes most sense to you and stick with it. quoting is like indentation - religious wars ensue regularly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a difference. Regardless, how you write block comments is your choice; in the normal case it does not matter as long as the comment begins with `/*` and ends with `*/`. Some documentation generators may care, but that varies too much to account for.

Yours is a common style, use it if it suits you and use it consistently.

Answer (score 0):

PHP supports

```
/* multiline
comment
*/
```

and

```
// inline comment
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php

Comment: It also supports Perl/bash/Python style comments, beginning with a `#`.